# I get a "Windows Script Host" error message when I download a standard(legit) JS file

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I'm using Windows 7. when I download a js file, the bottom left of the screen in Chrome where they show the file now says "this type of file can harm your computer, keep or discard". On my old computer I just clicked on the bottom of the screen and the file opened. Now I get this keep and discard message and then I get an error message which you can see in

[image: http://oi60.tinypic.com/33dcw1i.jpg]

the error box title says "Windows script host" Error : 'window' is undefined'. I just want to open the file. The file is from modernizer.

I hope the following didn't cause the error: I downloaded the link where it says "Enable_Folder_Drive_Library_Pin_to_Start_Menu.reg" [on this website](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5736-start-menu-pin-unpin-folder-drive-library.html) I hope it didn't mess up any registries. I don't know anything about that stuff and I hope that's not causing me the problems.

EDIT
Doesn't work on Firefox either.

Answer (score 0):

To "open" a script file means to run it (in Windows Script Host). If you just want to
see or edit the script, you should right-click the file and choose "Edit".